# How to edit an xml element with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I need help with the  tag. I can not make changes on this element with Jquery. I need to get the ID of it. Is it possible?

```
 <evidence type="1234" key="1">
    <source>
      <dbReference type="PDB" id="abcd"/>
    </source>
  </evidence>
```

Edit:
I am trying:

```
  var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel> 
  </rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $id = $( "dbReference" );
  alert("id");
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible using the standard jQuery methods. How are you retrieving this XML?

Comment: Hello there. I would be so glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` and `attr()`. This assumes you are only looking for one such element.

If there are more you would need to loop over the results of `find()`

```js
var str = `<evidence type="1234" key="1">
    <source>
      <dbReference type="PDB" id="abcd"/>
    </source>
  </evidence>`,

  $xml = $(str),
  id = $xml.find('dbReference').attr('id');

console.log('dbReference id= ', id)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```